# How to make divs to behave like the msg boxes in hangout or facebook chat?

Tags: html, css

It is hard to me to explain, but i am trying to do something like this:

msg me...............
............msg other
msg me...............
msg me...............

the msg have different width, so i need it to fill the space in the left and right with margin or something, i am trying something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="msg-me">
  <span>msg me msg me msg me msg me msg me msg me msg me msg me</span>
</div>

<div class="msg-other">
<span>msg other msg other msg other msg other msg other msg other </span>
</div>

<div class="msg-me">
<span>msg short</span>
</div>

<div class="msg-other">
<span>msg short</span>
</div>
```

then i am trying to float them to left and right, but it does get shorts msg in the same line and i have no idea how to keep every one in a different line. They look like this:

msg me........msg other
....msg other msg other

How can i make every div to be in a different line? Also the width of the divs need to adjust to the content. The best example of what i want to accomplish is hangout or facebook.

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mLa570ut/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your **CSS**

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

And for your **HTML**, add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after every `.msg-me` and `.msg-other`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="msg-me">
        <span>msg me msg me msg me msg me msg me msg me msg me msg me</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="msg-other">
        <span>msg other msg other msg other msg other msg other msg other </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="msg-me">
        <span>msg short</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="msg-other">
        <span>msg short</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**About `.clearfix`:**

This CSS class cleanses the after effect of float attribute which caused the weird structure that you see.

Comment: oh i see, i had tried with the Nicolas clearfix method and it wasnt working because i need a clearfix after every div, right? That was my mistake. <br> Thank you!!!